# Subject in Active voice

Tags: grammar

> The book fulfils my requirement.
>   The book is fulfilled my requirement.

Which one is correct?

If the 1st sentence is correct, do you have another examples that the subject are things in active voice?

Comment: The first sentence is correct. It is your requirement(s) that are fulfilled (or **met**) not the book.

Comment: What research have you done for this question? (e.g., [here](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/activepass.htm).)  Why are you having trouble?  The majority of written and spoken English is in active voice.  Understanding your problem will help us provide better quality answers.

Comment: @RonaldSole by your meaning, the sentence shall be "my requirement(subject) fulfils(verb) the book(object)."? Like" I(subject) eat(verb) the apple(object)."

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct.

The second sentence is not correct, because the passive verb "is fulfilled" doesn't have a direct object: "my requirement".

In the sentence "The book fulfils my requirement", [The book] is the subject. [fulfils] is the verb. [my requirement] is the object. The *verb* is active voice, present tense, third person singular. The subject and the object are not active voice, because nouns don't have an active or passive voice.

You ask for "examples that the subject are things in active voice".  This doesn't make sense. Because only verbs have an "active voice" or "passive voice". The subject is a noun.

Perhaps you mean active sentences where the subject is inanimate.

> The racquet plays an important role in tennis.
>
> My house keeps us safe and warm.
>
> The stone lies on the beach.